# How to match a value from on workbook on another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 workbooks.

I got it working to concat the 2 columns.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KISAz.png)

I want to see if values in Column C in one workbook will match with the concatenated column  on another workbook that has 3000 rows of charge codes.

And if it does match I want to see in column F if its "open" or "closed"

```
If "closed"
    Do msgBox "Charge code is closed"
```

I tried integrating and doing research on vlookup, index match, looking into binary search and dictionary/hash map. But dont know how to implement it with 2 different worksheets.

for example I have column c = job
and i will try to do a for loop for each job into range("A5:B3003"). But get stuck after that

EDIT :The code I have now populates timesheets for every employee every week so the name changes. That's why I need it in VBA.

ADDED picture

The top half of the data should be on the bottom to make the numbers in order for a binary search. Should I do that?

I am new to VBA

```
Sub FindOpenJobs()

Dim charge
charge = "L:\Operations\MGT_Tools\TimeCard_ReportGenerator\" & "*charge*"
Workbooks.Open charge



Dim JobNumberCellRow
Dim JobNumberCellCol
For JobNumberCellRow = 5 To 3003
JobNumberCellCol = "A"

Dim JobNumberCellString As String
JobNumberCellString = JobNumberCellCol & JobNumberCellRow

Dim JobNumberCellValue As String
JobNumberCellValue = Range(JobNumberCellString).Text


If Len(JobNumberCellValue) = 5 And IsNumeric(JobNumberCellValue) Then
    Dim DashNumberCellRow
    Dim DashNumberCellCol As String
    DashNumberCellRow = JobNumberCellRow
    DashNumberCellCol = Chr(Asc(JobNumberCellCol) + 1)
    
    Dim DashNumberCellString As String
    DashNumberCellString = DashNumberCellCol & DashNumberCellRow
    
    Dim DashNumberCellValue As String
    DashNumberCellValue = Range(DashNumberCellString).Text
    
    
    If (IsNumeric(Right(DashNumberCellValue, 3))) Then
            Dim StatusCellRow
            Dim StatusCellCol As String
            StatusCellRow = DashNumberCellRow
            StatusCellCol = Chr(Asc(DashNumberCellCol) + 4)
            Dim StatusCellString As String
            StatusCellString = StatusCellCol & StatusCellRow
                
            Dim StatusCellValue As String
            StatusCellValue = Range(StatusCellString).Text
           
            
            If StatusCellValue = "OPEN" Then
                Dim CompiledData As String
                CompiledData = JobNumberCellValue + DashNumberCellValue
                Debug.Print (CompiledData & " " & StatusCellValue)
                
                
            End If
            
            
            
    End If
End If

Next


Dim Folder As String
Dim FileName As String
Folder = "L:\Operations\MGT_Tools\TimeCard_ReportGenerator\Quickbooks\"
FileName = Dir(Folder & "*Quickbooks*")
Do While FileName <> ""
Workbooks.Open (Folder & FileName)
FileName = Dir()
    
    i = 4
    Do While Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 4))
    jobCells = Range("C" & i).Text
    Debug.Print jobCells
        If CompiledData <> jobCells Then
        MsgBox (jobCells & " " & "Job number doesnt exist")
    
        End If
        
    i = i + 1
    Loop
    
    
        
        
        
     
Loop
End Sub
```

EDIT2: This is the code i have so far but its not quite doing what i want it to do. The job numbers in C is only comparing to the last value which is L3003. But when i put the "next" further down the code the dialog box will open 9000 times.

Comment: Can you make a new column in the first workbook that does `=A1 & B1` so you can solve with a vlookup or countif?

Comment: Yes I can make a new column. I have this but column G doesnt populate anything.


Sub Concat()

    i = 238
    Do While Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 1))
    Range("G" & i) = Range("A" & i).Cells & Range("B" & i).Cells
    i = i + 1
    Loop
 
End Sub

Comment: Does any of the workbooks contain your posted code? What are their names? What are the worksheet names?

Comment: workbook with the chargeCodes i dim it to "charge". So i open it with "workbooks.open charge" with a worksheet name of "sheet1". The other one i have it opening by "Workbooks.Open Fold & File" with a wksheet name of Quickbooks_Results_20230604_CS. But fold = path and file = "quickbooks" with wildcards. Because i have code to open every "quickbooks" file in the folder cause it populates a new one every week.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use VBA to make the concatenation, and @JNevill proposes to put an Excel formula directly in your worksheet. Do you really need to use VBA?

If you need VBA, your code presented in your question work correctly for me, but It's difficult to help you because we have no idea about your data. Why do you begin your loop with i = 238? What is your result in the cell G238?

> Note : it's unusual for me to see Range.Cells like in 
> Range("G" & i) = Range("A" & i).Cells & Range("B" & i).Cells 
> Usually it's : 
> Range("G" & > i) = Range("A" & i).Value & Range("B" & i).Value 
> Or try to use Formula 
> to put a formula in your cells (it's a better habit) 
> Range("F" & > i).Formula = "A" & i & "B" & i

```
    Sub ConcatAandB()
        i = 238
            Do While Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 1))
                Range("G" & i) = Range("A" & i).Value & Range("B" & i).Value
                Range("H" & i).Formula = "=" & "A" & i & "&" & "B" & i
                Range("I" & i).Formula = "=CONCAT(" & "A" & i & "," & "B" & i & ")"
                '.Value is not mandatory try
                Range("J" & i) = Range("A" & i) & Range("B" & i)
                i = i + 1
            Loop
        End Sub
```

Try this code and look the difference in cells G238, H238, G238 and I238.

IMPORTANT :
In your question, you wrote :
"I have 2 workbooks." 
 Is there 2 workbook files or two worksheets in the same file? If it's in the same file, you need to activate the right sheet before to launch your VBA code. Manually or in your Sub.

Comment: I had it on i=238 because i edited to where it was in order for a binary search.

Comment: its 2 different workbook files

Comment: Can anybody help

Comment: @Jchau123 If you have two workbooks, and if your code tries to access some data in another workbook, you need to indicate the name of the Workbook and also the name of the Sheet. You will find easily different examples and different ways to code that in VBA.

Comment: Can anybody see the edit2 and see whats wrong with my code